# How to convert a HTML page into PDF?

Tags: pdf, html, wordpress

I have a page with a complex structure and some fancy stylings (look at those accordions etc.) https://animalso.com/breeds/chiweenie/

How do I create a PDF file from it, so it will remain all the info and look really nice?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You want the PDF to match exactly the webpage? My understanding of interactive PDFs is that for this to work you would have to create it originally in inDesign or something similar, rather than printing to a PDF.

Comment: What you've tried? Why that wasn't a solution?

Comment: <Control>-<P> and then "Print to PDF"?

Comment: The interactive accordion thing, the photo gallery links are probably not going to get converted to PDF easily.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/). Windows versions are available on the [downloads](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html) page.

`wkhtmltopdf http://animalso.com/breeds/chiweenie/ chiweenie.pdf`

Comment: Thanks! But is there any SaaS versions or software for Win 10? I'm not tech savvy :P

Comment: There is a Windows version. You can download it from here - https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

There aren't really any easy, free, "non-techy" answers that will produce nice PDFs of complex webpages like that one (that I know of). The easiest PDF-making method is just printing to a PDF using Chrome or Firefox, both of which support printing just a selection of the webpage, but neither of which can handle your page very well.

But if it's your own Wordpress site that you're trying to PDF-ify, you could try looking at some Wordpress plugins like [these](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/4-plugins-to-provide-pdfs-of-wordpress-posts-but-why-manual-is-better/) or [these](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/best-pdf-plugins-for-wordpress/). Those will allow you to grab your Wordpress content directly and produce a PDF, though again, the good ones tend to be paid.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using some online website which can help you to for different conversation here is the link

[TO convert](https://www.pdfonline.com/)

and specifically for HTML to PDF

[For Your Specific formate](https://web2.pdfonline.com/)

I have tried the link that you posted, and it works fine.